# Is there a maximum amount of artifact power a weapon can hold?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've been questing, killing rares, and collecting treasure for just a day now on about 3 characters, collecting many items to upgrade my Artifact Power.
Above the experience bar is another bar showing the current and total Artifact Power I have collected for my weapon:
At level 100 it was a maximum of 300.
After leveling to 101 and upgrading my weapon once it has a new maximum of 325.

However I realized, that is not the actual maximum.
When approaching the 300 mark, I was at 265 and clicked a +100 Artifact Power item, which put me at 300. I was a bit dissapointed that I just wasted 65 power, but after upgrading my weapon seconds later the bar reset to 65 / 325 power.

This means that my 65 power was not wasted, and the number shown on the bar is not the maximum.

That all being said, **is there a hard maximum amount of power your artifact can store without going to your Order Hall and upgrading it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That bar you are seeing has nothing to do with a cap. That is the artifact power required to unlock the next trait, nothing more. It's mainly there to just remind you to go unlock a new trait when you have enough.

By the time you finish your artifact, with all 34 traits and all 20 of the final dump trait you will have spent 65,256,330 Artifact Power. It's impossible to waste AP, so don't worry and just keep collecting.

Comment: There are a few things to waste artifact power: choosing the wrong traits (undoing them costs some ap) and powering up the wrong weapon.

Comment: You'll eventually fully upgrade all your artifacts (theoretically) so the only wasted points would be anything you earn after fully unlocking all traits for every artifact for your class. That won't be happening any time soon. Choosing the wrong trait is not "wasting" any power. That power is still there and you get some benefit from it.

Comment: @NathanK choosing a wrong trait and undoing it(!) is a waste. If you keep it, it won't hurt your AP, but maybe your character's performance. Please read the whole sentence and not just parts of it.

Comment: @dly Respeccing your artifact you lose some, yes. Easy solution: don't do it. Pick the wrong trait? Oops, just save up and pick the next one instead of handicapping yourself by respeccing.